# Leaflet: How can I add a marker to map only on mouseover another marker?

Tags: leaflet, mouseover, marker

**I have a polygon and two markers. The last marker (var power) I want to start only on mouseover or onclick the first marker (var myIcon). How can I do that? Could you please take a look on this code?**

```
var polygon = new L.Polygon(line, {
    color: pastel,
    weight: 0.1,
    opacity: 0.1,
    fillColor: pastel,
    fillOpacity: 0.04,    
    interactive: true   
});
polygon.addTo(map)
} 

var myIcon = L.divIcon({
    className: 'divIcon',
    iconSize: new L.Point(35, 15),
    iconAnchor:[18, 20],
    zIndexOffset: 1000,
    html: '<?=$desc1[$i]?>'
});
var marker = L.marker([x1, y1], {icon: myIcon})
.addTo(map)

marker.refPoly = polygon;
marker.on('mouseover', function(e) {
    e.target.refPoly.setStyle({
    fillOpacity: 0.48  
    });
});
marker.on('mouseout', function(e) {
    e.target.refPoly.setStyle({
    fillOpacity: 0.04
    });
});

var power = <?php echo json_encode($watt); ?>;
var power = power.reverse();
var myPower = L.divIcon({
    className: 'divPower',
    iconSize: new L.Point(25, 12),
    iconAnchor:[12, 5], 
    html: power[b]
}); 
    L.marker(pointC, {icon: myPower}).addTo(map)
    .bindTooltip(350-b*10 + '°');
```

Comment: What do you mean with "start only on mouseover"? Do you mean to display the marker only on mouseover?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, this is what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove a marker with `marker.removeFrom(map)` and add it to the map with `marker.addTo(map)`:

```
var marker = L.marker([x1, y1], {icon: myIcon})
.addTo(map)
marker.refPoly = polygon;


var power = <?php echo json_encode($watt); ?>;
var power = power.reverse();
var myPower = L.divIcon({
    className: 'divPower',
    iconSize: new L.Point(25, 12),
    iconAnchor:[12, 5], 
    html: power[b]
}); 

// I removed .addTo(map). Then the marker is not displayed from beginning
var powerMarker = L.marker(pointC, {icon: myPower})
    .bindTooltip(350-b*10 + '°');


marker.on('mouseover', function(e) {
    e.target.refPoly.setStyle({
       fillOpacity: 0.48  
    });
    powerMarker.addTo(map);
});
marker.on('mouseout', function(e) {
    e.target.refPoly.setStyle({
       fillOpacity: 0.04
    });
    powerMarker.removeFrom(map);
});

marker.on('click', function(e) {
    powerMarker.addTo(map);
});
```

Comment: Yes, your code will work great and would display one marker on mouseover or onclick. But my problem is I have to display a lot of markers in loop. I think if I go to mouseover the loop has expired and this is the reason why it shows only the last marker in the loop.

Comment: Please share your code with the loop else I can't help. The best would be to create a new question

Comment: I've done a new question. It's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66945337/leaflet-osm-how-can-i-display-markers-in-loop-around-a-polygon-on-mouseover  Thanks.